# ECONNREFUSED when using node with nano and couchdb

Tags: node.js, express, couchdb, couchdb-nano, iriscouch

I was using nodejs + nano + couchdb for my application successfully up until today. For some reason all of a sudden I'm getting ECONNREFUSED when I try to run my application. If I try to query the database using the web browser or using a different application (java application) it works fine. I'm uncertain why just in this scenario it stopped working. I've been researching for the past 2 days and can't find any help. I believe this might have something to do with too many open connections, but that's a little bit out of my realm of knowledge. Can anyone provide me with any insight on debugging this issue or any direction I could go in? I should mention this couchdb lives on iriscouch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more information about stack that you're using. But basically it's server machine doesn't want to allow connecting. Also try run your app with DEBUG=*, nano will log via console.log almost everything.

E.g. change in `package.json` start command to `node changetoyourapp.js DEBUG=*`

I faced yesterday same issue with nodejitsu/iriscouch. Issue disappeared after some restarts.

Answer (score 2):

This is down to Node v18 now preferring an IPv6 address over and IPv4 address if two exist for the same hostname.

i.e. if your `/etc/hosts` contains entries like this:

```
127.0.0.1          localhost
::1                localhost
```

Node v16 will say that "localhost" resolves to `127.0.0.1` where Node v18 will say "localhost" resolves to `::1`, the IPv6 equivalent. As CouchDB doesn't listen on an IPv6 port by default, then a connection to `::1` will be refused.

Solutions:

1. Use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in your URLs.
2. Use a domain name that resolves unambiguously to an IPv4 address e.g. `127.0.0.1       my.pretend.host` in your `/etc/hosts` file.
3. Revert to Nodev16 which preferred IPv4 addresses in its dns lookup.
4. Make CouchDB bind to an IPv6 address by changing `bind_address = ::1` in couchdb.ini. You can then do `curl 'http://USER:PASS@[::1]:5984/`.

See

https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano/issues/313#issuecomment-1321760360

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of your node vs the expected node version of nano. It is possible that nano does not work with node > 16.